# Exclude dependency jars in gradle using regular expression syntax

Tags: gradle

I can include jars from a folder in gradle script using below code:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')// libs -> folder in root directory
```

I can exclude a jar from a folder in gradle script using below code:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'antlr-2.7.7.jar')
```

I can exclude multiple jars using below code:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: ['antlr-2.7.7.jar', 'antlr-runtime-3.3.jar'])
```

But I could not exclude jars using regular expression way, like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'antlr-.*.jar')
```

The above line wouldn't give any error but it will not exclude the two antlr jars. Is it possible to achieve this in gradle.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure that is passed to `exclude`, e.g.:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: { e -> e.name.startsWith('ant') })
```

When you have a `name` of the element you can use regex as well, instead of `startsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html), you can use a slightly less terse syntax to use more explicit sets of files, similar to Ant filesets, with a set difference operator.

```
allJars=fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
antlrJars=fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'antlr-.*.jar')
jarsToUse=allJars-antlrJars
```